# how to lineup the agents in the ascending or descending order of their who number in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo, agent

I am creating an patient-surgeon-operation bed model, wherein I need to show surgeons lined up on the left side of patch awaiting to enter operation room in the center and the patients awaiting in the queue from the right side.

I want the surgeons and patients to be located on the patch as per their `who` number

S1 S2 S3 --> Operation room < -- P1 P2 P3

I use the below query, I am not sure where to incorporate the who number

```
to lineup-patients
  LET gapp 10                    
  LET directions 
  [45 90 230 180 45 90 230 180 45 90 45 90 230 180 45 90 230 180 45 90 45 90 ]
  LET jj 0                        ; counter / index
  REPEAT initial-number-patients
  [ create-PATIENTS 1
    [  SETXY (0 + jj * gapp) 20
      set shape "person"
      SET size 1.2
      SET label who
      SET label-color black
      SET heading item jj directions
    ]
    SET jj jj + 1
    ASK patients [
      MOVE-TO ONE-OF PATCHES WITH [ PCOLOR = yellow ]
  ] ]
END
```

Comment: I am new to netlogo, also tried using lists, but am not able to get them lined up on the patch as per who number       to lineup-patients     let number-of-list 3      let patients-per-list 7      let gapp 10       let jj 0    REPEAT initial-number-patients    
[ create-patients   initial-number-patients    
[ SETXY ( 0 + jj * gapp ) 20        
  set groups [] ; empty list       
      set groups lput who ["number-of-list"]       
      set shape "person"        
  ]     
  ASK patients [       
      MOVE-TO ONE-OF PATCHES WITH [ PCOLOR = yellow ] SET color random 126 ] ]        
End

Comment: Ok. Remember to format your code by adding  4 leading space to each line of code next time.

Comment: Yes, i will thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `move-to` after you line them up.  And it always moves all existing patients.  To keep things cleaner, write a separate `lineup` proc.

```
to lineup [#patients #patch #gap]
  let _x ([pxcor] of #patch)
  let _y ([pycor] of #patch)
  let _xqs n-values (count #patients) [[n] -> _x + n * #gap]
  (foreach sort #patients _xqs [
    [p x] -> ask p [setxy x _y]
  ])
end
```

You can test this with a new instance of NetLogo as follows:

```
to test
  ca
  crt 20
  lineup turtles one-of patches 0.5
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan. It gives lined up patients. I just did not understand whats _xqs and [p x], if you can explain this would be grateful.

Comment: The `_xqs` are the x-axis locations for the queued patients.  See the documentation for `n-values`.  The `[p x]` are the local variables (for a patient and an x-axis location) used in the loop.  See the documentation for using `foreach` with multiple lists. Hth.