# Sort agents' coordinate using array in NetLogo

Tags: arrays, coordinates, netlogo

I need to create a simulation code in NetLogo where agents from nest spread out in world to find food. There will be 10 agents in the nest.

The problem I'm facing now is I need to arrange these agents' position in the nest so that they won't overlap each other. Thus, I plan to sort their position using an array.

But I'm having problem to specify their location using array since I'm still struggling to undertsand NetLogo.

The code below is my attempt to write an array but to no avail.

```
to setup
  ca
  create-turtles 10
  [
    set size 2
 ]
  setup-patches
  sort-agent  
end

to sort-agent
  let n turtles
foreach sort turtles [ setup-nest
  ask turtles
  [
    set plabel n
    set n n + 1
  ]
]
end

to setup-patches                                          
  ask patches
  [ setup-nest]
end

to setup-nest
   set nest? (distancexy 0 0) < 6
end
```

Can someone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577394

Comment: Your question is unclear, to me anyway. Can you edit it to be more specific and precise about what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @alan thank you for suggesting that link, but I think this code is not suitable for my project, thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: @SethTisue thanks for your comment, I have edited my question, if it still doesn't clear to you, just tell me, I'll edit again. :D

Comment: @linda It looks like [layout-circle](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#layout-circle) will meet your needs.

Comment: I still have no idea what "I plan to sort their position using an array" means or why you want to do that.. And while "I need to arrange these agents' position in the nest so that they won't overlap each other", is clear it's also extremely general and vague — how do you propose to do that?

Comment: Since I don't want those agents to overlap each other, it's better to specify their location first, 

that's why I plan to use array to arrange agents position in nest. by using array, they won't overlap each other.

Comment: @Alan thanks for the suggestion, I will try it

Comment: "by using array, they won't overlap each other" — why? I don't know what that means or why you think that. you'll need to explain your thinking there. How do you propose to prevent the turtles from overlapping, exactly?

Comment: @SethTisue "by using array, they won't overlap each other" — why? --->because I plan to arrange agent position in nest using array, When I'm arranging their position, I will make sure they won't overlap...... example for i =0, i > 0, i++, AgentPosition(i); ----> something like this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create turtles that are spread out, select random patches and use `sprout` (assuming there are fewer turtles required than patches available). Based on your comments in response to Seth's answer, I think this is more what you want. I would like to reiterate his comment that you are trying to do too much at once. An obvious break here would be to create the nest (and check that works) before even thinking about creating the turtles within the nest.

```
globals [nest]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-nest
  setup-turtles
end

to setup-nest
  set nest patches with [distancexy 0 0 < 6]
  ask nest [ set pcolor red ]
end

to setup-turtles
  ask n-of 10 nest
  [ sprout 1
    [ set label who
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Yes~! this is how I plan to do, thank you so much. and thanks for the advice, I'll try to do it one by one next time.

Answer (score 2):

By `let n turtles`, I think you probably meant `let n count turtles`. By `set plabel n`, I think you probably mean `set label n` (you want to label the turtles, not the patch they're standing on, right?).

It's unclear why you call `setup-nest` inside `sort-agent`. I think you simply want to remove that?

It's also unclear why you put a call to `ask turtles` inside your `foreach` loop. `ask turtles` always asks all turtles; I assume your intent was to ask some particular turtle, here...?

I doubt you need to use a list at all here. (NetLogo calls them lists, not arrays.)  If I understood the problem you were trying to solve better, perhaps I'd decide involving lists make sense, but for now, I'm skeptical.

If you simply want to label the turtles according to the order they were created, you can just do:

```
ask turtles [ set label who ]
```

Or even if label at the time you create them:

```
create-turtles 10 [ set label who ]
```

But if this isn't suitable for some reason, a way to accomplish the same thing, with similar code to what you provided, is:

```
let n 0
foreach sort turtles [
  ask ? [
    set label n
    set n n + 1
  ]
]
```

You don't say if you're using NetLogo 5 or 6.  I've used NetLogo 5 syntax, but I can change it to 6 if you want.

As a general remark, it appears to me you are trying to write too much code all at once. As a result, the code you're writing has so many things wrong with it that you're going to have a lot of trouble trying to fix all of them at the same time. I'd suggest starting with working code and then try to make *very small* improvements to it, one at a time, getting each improvement working as you go. Anytime you're having to write a bunch of code at all once, that means you're tackling too big a problem and you should find a smaller version of it to tackle first.

Comment: I'm using NetLogo 5.2, and yes, setup-nest should be inside sort-agent, now I realized that... I wrote it there because I want to ask all turtles don't overlap each other in nest.

Comment: Imagine that nest is a classroom, and agents are students, before class start, all students are sitting at their own place, they know their place ------> so here, I want to code agents to sit in specific position in nest, so when I press setup, agents already at their place-------> my best guess on how to do this by using list/ array (now I know it called list, thank you), ------> but if there any other way to do this besides lists, I'm open to suggestion. My knowledge on how NetLogo works are so limited.

Comment: Okay, open a new question the next time you get stuck.

Comment: thanks, I will do that. And thank you so much for spending your time to entertain my question, Mr Seth.